# How to find a specific word in xml file and print all the children tags using python?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing

If I have something like that:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<movies xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="moviescheme.xsd">
 <movie>
  <title>Million Dollar Baby</title>
  <formattype>video</formattype>
  <genre>Drama</genre>
  <genre>Sport</genre>
  <released>
   2004
  </released>
  <rate>
  <rottentomatoes>91%</rottentomatoes>
  <imbd>8.1</imbd>
  </rate>
 </movie>
 <movie>
  <title>Room</title>
  <formattype>video</formattype>
  <genre>Drama</genre>
  <released>
   2015
  </released>
  <rate>
  <rottentomatoes>94%</rottentomatoes>
  <imbd>8.2</imbd>
  </rate>
 </movie>
</movies>
```

How can I search for the word "Room" for instance , get all the related tags -children of the related movie tag- to it and print it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use lxml with an xpath for a tutorial see http://lxml.de/tutorial.html

```
from lxml import etree
# Read the xml file.
root = etree.parse("movies.xml")
# get the movie element with the title test Room
elems = root.xpath("//movie[title/text()='Room']")
# for the child elments print the data recursing through other children
def printitems (elems):
    for i in elems:
        print("%s - %s" % (i.tag, i.text))
        printitems(i)

printitems (elems[0])
```

gives

```
title - Room
formattype - video
genre - Drama
released - 
   2015

rate - 

rottentomatoes - 94%
imbd - 8.2
```

**Edited to recurse through child nodes of children.**

Comment: Thanks a lot ,that was helpful.